# Checking error condition in tesclass

Tags: apex, failing-tests

I want a test class like:

```
if system.runAs(user) {
    Test.startTest();

    delete new List<Sobject>(); // should give error.

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

How can I do this in my test class?

Comment: You need to use System.assert methods. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm

Comment: How can i use that like  List<Database.Saveresult> res= Database.delete(List, true);..what will go in System.asserts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually prefer to use the following pattern when you need an all-or-none test:

```
try {
    delete records;
    System.assert(false, "Expected DMLException");
} catch(DMLException e) {
    // Validate specific errors here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sfdcfox...so in expected DMLException what should we give..the full error which we are getting or something else

Comment: @DavidMycka See [Exception Class and Built-in Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm) in the developer's guide for usage of DMLException (it's near the bottom of the document). You can verify specific error texts, which field(s) are associated with the error, etc.